# How can I rename a file in code in Inno Setup?

Tags: cmd, inno-setup, pascalscript

I need to rename a file to zip, I try this code but doesn't works.

```pascal
 Exec('cmd.exe', 'rename '+ExpandConstant('{app}\scripts\set.bat'+' set.zip'), '', SW_SHOW,
      ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

I found a way to do it on `[Run]` section, but I need it to do in `[Code]` section.

Comment: RenameFile() http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_renamefile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to quote the paths, as `{app}` typically contains spaces (`Program Files`).
2. You need `/C` command-line parameter before the command.

```pascal
Exec('cmd.exe',
     '/C rename ' + AddQuotes(ExpandConstant('{app}\scripts\set.bat')) + ' set.zip',
     '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

---

Though as @Alex correctly commented, use [`RenameFile`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_renamefile) instead:

```pascal
RenameFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\scripts\set.bat'), ExpandConstant('{app}\scripts\set.zip'));
```

Comment: I found my error, was using:  `RenameFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\scripts\unset.bat'), 'unset.zip');`